# Animated SVG not working in Android Webview

Tags: android, svg-animate

I have a web app that includes an animated SVG that builds up a set of faces, adding a new face every second or so. You start with one face and end up with 12 say, all in the same SVG file. The web app works fine when opened in a desktop browser.

When I run the web app in a browser on an Android device, or in a WebView which is where I ultimately want to run it, the animation goes weird. The first face is presented then a second later all the rest appear, there is no face-by-face build up.

I know from other readings that Android Studio is not great with animated SVG. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909932/svg-animation-not-working-in-android-webview) for example is an similar question that is unanswered and 7 years old.

Because the SVG is embedded in HTML I do not have the option of VectorDrawable, and WebView should handle HTML+CSS+JavaScript+SVG correctly anyway.

I am hoping things have improved and someone has some suggestions on where to start. Specifically is there some markup I can add to AndroidManifest.xml or some code I can add to  MainActivity.java that will make WebView render animated SVG correctly?

Comment: `I know from other readings that Android Studio is not great with animated SVG.` don't really understand what this has to do with android studio, considering that's just the IDE you're using to build your app. if you're unable to do something, then it's probably because of android, not android-studio :)

Comment: If Android browsers don't render SVG animation correctly, WebView won't do better. WebView is much worse than a browser. You can only replace SVG with a GIF or make your own JavaScript animation.

Comment: Thanks @CoolMind, when you say JavaScript animation do you mean animate the SVG using JavaScript or animate a canvas, or either. How would you do it?

Comment: @MarkKortink, you are welcome! I am not frontend developer, so, I thought you could divide a whole SVG into individual pictures and animate them using JavaScript, if it was possible. Also you can place SVG files into `assets` folder and load from there, not accessing them via network, but it may be difficult for JS in WebView, also you should place HTML into `assets`.